# How to set a title on BottomSheetDialog with grid?

Tags: java, android, customdialog

I have created a `BottomSheetDialog` with a `GridView`, but I know that `BottomSheetDialog` can't set a title using the method `.setTitle()`, so how can I set a title on the dialog?

Here's my code:

**Activity:**

```
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);

    GridView gridView = new GridView(this);
    gridView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    gridView.setNumColumns(5);

    BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(gridView);
    bottomSheetDialog.show();
```

**CustomAdapter:**

```
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<String> sizeCodes;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        this.sizeCodes = Collections.emptyList();
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public CustomAdapter addItems(List<SizeData> items) {
        sizeCodes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (SizeData item : items)
            sizeCodes.add(item.getSize());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sizeCodes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return sizeCodes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_size_picker, parent, false);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.content)).setText(sizeCodes.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }
```

**item_size_picker:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why not just add your own title `View`? You could stick that `GridView` in vertical `LinearLayout` with the `TextView` above it, then pass the whole shebang to `setContentView()`. You could continue to do it programatically, or you could make a layout for it to inflate and setup before you pass it.

Comment: My `GridView` is programatically created. Let me put the rest of the code on the question for a better understanding.

Comment: We don't need it. You've shown enough. My first comment still applies.

Comment: So how can I do it? I'm not seeing how.

Comment: If you want to do it programatically, then `LinearLayout content = new LinearLayout(this); content.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); TextView title = new TextView(this); title.setText("Your Title"); content.addView(title);`, then insert your `GridView` stuff, then `content.addView(gridView); ... bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(content);`.

Comment: OMG, I'm feeling stupid right now hahahahaha.
Thanks, it works.